# SharePoint Document Center upload error

Tags: file-upload

I have:

- SharePoint 2010 SP1 instance.
- Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

The issue is that any uploads from within office (e.g. Save As or Save and Send) that try to save to SharePoint go through the Upload Center. The upload center fails with the message "Your changes were saved but could not be uploaded because of an error..."

This is consistent for all documents (even .txt) uploaded through Office or SharePoint Workspace. Direct uploads from the site are fine, as is the webdav interface.

There are no errors in the SharePoint logs.

What is the likely cause for this failure?

Update:

Further investigation led to the SharePoint server logs, not the client. The error there was...

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/41149443
Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/_vti_bin/cellstorage.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Service 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.CellStorages' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Service 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.CellStorages' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.EnsureThereAreNonMexEndpoints(ServiceDescription description)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
Process Name: w3wp
Process ID: 2172
```

Which, it turns out, is just a wordy way of saying that something terminally messed with your web.config and you should [restore the CellStorage service information](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/684c5f1a-97ff-4e87-9ffa-439c5d40b800).

Answer (score 1):

Had sort of the same problem some time ago. To solve it I went to the folder:

"C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\14.0\OfficeFileCache" and found out that it contained a lot of files. By temporarly moving the files outside of the folder I found out that it started to work again.

Reference: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/172/t/45583.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but not a fix for documents failing to upload correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The web.config had been erased. A copy of the web.config was restored, fixing the issue. [See](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/684c5f1a-97ff-4e87-9ffa-439c5d40b800)

Answer (score 0):

The problem could also be because of reaching the limit of minor versions (511).
Step 1: Publish a major version and check if that didn't solve the issue then try Step 2.
Step 2: Download a copy and upload it again that will solve the issue as it solved for me.